# How do I add text to each item in a list

Tags: python

I want to add text to each item in a list and then it back into the list.

Example

```
foods = [pie,apple,bread]
phrase = ('I like')
statement = [(phrase) + (foods) for phrase in foods]
```

I want to have the output (I like pie, I like apple, I like bread)

It prints out something along the lines of (hI like,pI like,pI like)

Comment: Unless `pie`, `apple`, `bread` are previously defined variables, the above is invalid Python. Perhaps you meant `['pie', 'apple', 'bread']`.

Comment: Strange, I don't get output like that. First I get `NameError: name 'pie' is not defined`. If I assign values to pie/apple/bread, then I get `TypeError: must be str, not list`. Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer string formatting:

```
foods = ['pie','apple','bread']

phrase = 'I like'

statement = ['{0} {1}'.format(phrase, j) for j in foods]

# Python 3.6+
statement = [f'{phrase} {j}' for j in foods]
```

Answer (score 2):

You should avoid declaring phrase on another line, here is the sample that should make it.

```
statement = ['I like ' + food for food in foods]  # Note the white space after I like
```

In your code you probably coded it too quickly because you are reasigning the value of phrase with the `for phrase in foods`. Also when you do `phrase + foods` foods is a list which cannot be concatenated with string

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a container and use `.format`:

```
phrase = 'I like {}'
statement = [phrase.format(food) for food in ("pie","apple","bread")]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foods = ['pie','apple','bread']

phrase = 'I like'

statement = [phrase + ' ' + j for j in foods]

>>> statement
['I like pie', 'I like apple', 'I like bread']
```

The problem in your code was that you were using the iterator incorrectly.